# Find Cartesian equation of $x=\frac{1+t^2}{1-t^2}, y = \frac{2t}{1-t^2}$

Tags: functions

I am studying pure maths as a hobby. I am stuck on the following: Find the Cartesian equation of $x=\frac{1+t^2}{1-t^2}, y = \frac{2t}{1-t^2}$

I know I need to eliminate t but cannot find how to do it. I have added the equations to get $x+y = \frac{t+1}{1-t}$, I have divided them to get $\frac{x}{y} = \frac{1+t^2}{2t}$ but I cannot find how to isolate *t* so as to get an equation purely in terms of *x* and *y*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$x-y=\frac{(1-t)^2}{1-t^2}=\frac{1-t}{1+t}=\frac1{x+y}$$ so $$x^2-y^2=1$$

Comment: ... therefore an equilateral hyperbola.

Comment: You might be interested by my answer giving an interpretation of parameter $t$.

Answer (score 4):

Put $t=\tan(m)$ ,  therefore

$y=\tan(2m)$ and $ x=\sec(2m)$.

Now as we know that $1+\tan^2 (x) =\sec^2 (x) $.
We get , $1+y^2=x^2$ .

Comment: I like the way you use (circular trigonometry) Weierstrass substitution rules. I have made the jump : I use the hyperbolic version of these rules.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach:

Let us recall that there exists expressions called ["Weierstrass substitution formulas"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution) for circular trigonometry:

$$\cos a =\dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, \ \ \sin a =\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2}, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \text{where} \ \ t:=\tan(\tfrac{a}{2})$$

They have the avantage to turn trigonometric formulas into rational expressions.

There are completely analogous formulas (see bottom paragraph "hyperbolic functions" in the reference given above) for hyperbolic trigonometry:

$$\cosh a = \frac{1 + t^2}{1 - t^2}, \quad \sinh a = \frac{2t}{1 - t^2}, \ \ \quad  \quad \ \ \text{where} \ \ t:=\tanh(\tfrac{a}{2})$$

Therefore, classical relationship:

$$\cosh^2 a - \sinh^2 a = 1$$

becomes:

$$\left(\frac{1 + t^2}{1 - t^2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{2t}{1 - t^2}\right)^2 = 1$$

otherwise said:

$$x^2-y^2=1.$$